# What is the difference between ${@:2} and ${*:2} in these cases?

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

Given the following code in bash:

```
filename=${1} 
content1=${@:2}
content2="${@:2}"
content3=${*:2}
content4="${*:2}"
echo  "${content1}" > "${filename}"
echo   "${content2}" >> "${filename}"
echo  "${content3}" >> "${filename}"
echo   "${content4}" >> "${filename}"
```

What is the difference between the "contents" ? When I will see the difference? What is the better way to save the content that I get and why?

Answer (score 2):

In an assignment, the right-hand side doesn't have to be quoted to prevent word splitting and globbing, unless it contains a blank.

These two are the same:

```
myvar=$var
myvar="$var"
```

but these are not:

```
myvar='has space'
myvar=has space
```

The last one tries to run a command `space` with the environment variable `myvar` set to value `has`.

This means that `content1` is the same as `content2`, and `content3` is the same as `content4`, as they only differ in RHS quoting.

The differences thus boil down to the difference between `$@` and `$*`; the fact that subarrays are used doesn't matter. Quoting from the manual:

(for [`$*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_0024_002a)):

> When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the `IFS` special variable.

(for [`$@`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_0024_0040)):

> When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.

Since you're using quotes (as you almost always should when using `$@` or `$*`), the difference is that `"${*:2}"` is a single string, separated by the first character of `IFS`, and `"${@:2}"` expands to separate words, blank separated.

Example:

```
$ set -- par1 par2 par3      # Set $1, $2, and $3
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${@:2}"   # Separate words
<par2>
<par3>
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${*:2}"   # Single word, blank separated (default IFS)
<par2 par3>
$ IFS=,                      # Change IFS
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${*:2}"   # Single word, comma separated (new IFS)
<par2,par3>
```

As for when to use `$@` vs. `$*`: as a rule of thumb, you *almost always* want `"$@"` and *almost never* the unquoted version of either, as the latter is subject to word splitting and globbing.

`"$*"` is useful if you want to join array elements into a single string as in the example, but the most common case, I guess, is iterating over positional parameters in a script or function, and that's what `"$@"` is for. See also [this Bash Pitfall](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_arg_in_.24.2A).

Comment: But if I will get the paramater like that "a [need to be here some spaces]   b" (with some spaces between 'a' to 'b') so, I need to define it as `var="${1}"` , no ? (If I want to save about the spaces)

Comment: @AskMath No, try it: `var1='has     spaces'; var2=$var1; echo "<$var2>"`

Comment: @AskMath Or with a positional parameter: `set -- 'has    spaces'; var=$1; echo "<$var>"`

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that using `$*` will cause the arguments to be concatenated with the first character of `IFS`, while `$@` will cause the arguments to be concatenated with a single space (regardless of the value of `IFS`):

```
$ set a b c
$ IFS=-
$ c1="$*"
$ c2="$@"
$ echo "$c1"
a-b-c
$ echo "$c2"
a b c
```

The quotes aren't particularly important here, as expansions on the right-hand side of an assignment aren't subject to word-splitting or pathname expansion; `content1` and `content2` should always be identical, as should be `content3` and `content4`.

Which is better depends on what you *want*.

Comment: But given the following input `"s \space\space\space\space s"` I get `content1=s s`  \neq `content2= s \space\space\space\space s` (while "\spcae" need be a real space)

Comment: You'll have to show me a `set` command that produces that result.

Comment: if you will define the words iside " "  and puts more than one space between two letters

Comment: @chepner `c2="$@"` will this **always** be separated by spaces? Could you please point me to some documentation?

Comment: The man page description of `@` (under Special Parameters) only says that `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" ...` (in contrast to the description of `"$*"` as `"$1c$2c..."`, `c` being the first character of `IFS`). However, it doesn't really give any explicit description of `"$@"` in the case where field-splitting wouldn't be applied (as is the case here). POSIX appears to leave the behavior undefined, which is borne out by `dash` using `IFS` to join the fields in both `foo="$@"` and `foo="$*"`. Whether `bash` is intentionally using a single space is unclear.